# Accessing JAVA classes and functions from CFML - Object instantiation exception

Tags: java, coldfusion

I want to access a JAVA function from CFML script:

```
<cfscript>
    authToken = createobject("java","coldfusion.security.SecurityManager").createAuthToken('admin', 'cfadmin', '12345', false);
</cfscript>
<cfoutput>authToken: #authToken#</cfoutput>
```

I got the following error:

> Object instantiation exception.
>
> An exception occurred while instantiating a Java object. The class
>   must not be an interface or an abstract class. If the class has a
>   constructor that accepts an argument, you must call the constructor
>   explicitly using the init(args) method. Error :
>   coldfusion.security.SecurityManager

I know is because the arguments passed directly to `createAuthToken` that I can't do and I should init() it. How can I correctly pass the arguments in this scenario?

Comment: You have to pass the *correct* arguments to the pseudo-constructor `init()` - not a method of the class. From what I can tell, the constructor for that class expects completely different arguments than what you are using anyway, hence it will not work even using `init()`. Out of curiosity, why do you need to use an internal class? What is the goal? Also, are you aware it is undocumented and may change in future versions?

Comment: I do some pentesting some of my customers servers. yes I know the functions are undocumented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It pretty much tells you what you need to do in the error message. But for the sake of clarity:

```
<cfset authToken = createobject("java","coldfusion.security.SecurityManager")
                    .init() // you might need some init() args here?
                    .createAuthToken('admin', 'cfadmin', '12345', false)
>
```

I'm not really sure why you bother to put that sinple statement into a `<cfscript>` block, btw. Would not a `<cfset>` do?

Comment: `createAuthToken` is defined as `public String createAuthToken(String username, String appName, String password, boolean isNTLM)` should I put those args in the `init()`?

Comment: No, you need to pass the arguments each method is expecting *to that method*. So if `createAuthToken()` is expecting that lot, then you need to pass it that lot. You need to look at the constructor(s) for `SecurityManager` to see what you need to pass to `init()` (`init()` just explicitly calls a constructor).

Comment: `<cfset authToken = createobject("java","coldfusion.security.SecurityManager")
                    .init('admin', 'cfadmin', '12345', false)       
                    .createAuthToken('admin', 'cfadmin', '12345', false)>` gives me `Unable to find a constructor for class coldfusion.security.SecurityManager that accepts parameters of type ( java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String ).` - I hate Java :)

Comment: What lead you to think that there was a constructor taking those args in the first place? What reference are you looking at?

Comment: In the Java source: `public String createAuthToken(String username, String appName, String password, boolean isNTLM)`

Comment: I'll try again. What lead you to think that there was a ***constructor*** taking those args. Not the method. The constructor.

Comment: You could try to JavaCast() the boolean value.  JavaCast("boolean", false)

Comment: In this case, javacast will not help. That class does not have a no-arg constructor, and the one it does have expects completely different arguments. To make it work, they need to pass the correct arguments to the constructor. Then they can invoke `createAuthToken()`.